# Postgresql: can't rename the database

Tags: database, rename, postgresql, database-administration

PostgreSQL 9.4.1 (installed with homebrew)
I want to rename a database. I'm doing this:

```
$ psql postgres
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE snot RENAME TO snortdb
postgres-# \l

                               List of databases
 Name    |   Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |    Access privileges    
 --------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------------------------
 postgres| myUser    | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
  snot   | snort     | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
template0| myUser    | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/myUser              +
         |           |           |         |       | myUser=CTc/myUser
template1| myUser    | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/myUser              +
         |           |           |         |       | myUser=CTc/myUser
```

As you can see the name didn't change. What am I doing wrong?
And actually why does the **=** changes to **-** after performing 'ALTER DATABASE' command? what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon (;) after the query?